# Xamarin Forms in visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to create an Android Xamarin Forms app, its working fine in Xamarin Studio but i cant find the assemblies to add to Visual Studio, cant find the namespaces, where are the Xamarin assemblies store?

Comment: Xamarin Forms packages are available from nuget.   The core assemblies for Android and iOS are installed by the Xamarin installer.  You may want to re-run the installer if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Visual Studio integration you will have to have at least a business level license with Xamarin - otherwise you can only use Xamarin Studio.